# why particles are not shown in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

This is my code...

```css
body
{ 
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100vh;

}
#particles-js
{ 

height:100%;
background:#f00;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>RESUME</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="p.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js">
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="particles.js"</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am beginner in javascript and jquery. I want to add particles in background of my webpage.I downloaded particles-js-master zip file from github and add particles.js and app.js in my html file. but it not working in any browser.did i wrong something? please help me out....thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's a syntax error where the code includes the `.js` files.

Comment: @Kingsley yeh..got it..its my silly mistake